# Logo image of my website is blurry on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, blurry, graphical-logo

Logo Image (as well as any image in the footer) appears blurry on mobile devices, but looks fine on computer screen.
Anyway to solve this?

here's my html file:

```
<div class="logo">
   <a href="/public_html/index.html">
       <img src="images/icon/logo-white.png" alt="Tatee" />
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the CSS also ?

Comment: img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

Comment: Try giving some fix width to it like, `width: 200px` and see is the image visible to you properly

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to use the logo div style as the same width as the image. For example, if logo dimension is like 100px * 50px - In that case, the CSS would be like,

```
.logo{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
.logo img{
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

You can try that way to work on mobile devices. Also, you can help with the media query to work that on the mobile device only.

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .logo{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .logo img{
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```